# Formula for expectation of $\mathrm{Tr}((A + X)^{-1})$ where $X$ is Wishart and $A$ is positive definite?

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request, trace, random-matrices

Let $X \sim \mathcal{W}_d(V, n)$ be a Wishart matrix and $A$ a real symmetric positive definite matrix.

I am interested in the following function
$$
\phi(A) := \mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\mathbb{E}\big[\big(X + A \big)^{-1}\big] \Big\}.
$$
I know that in general quantities like this should be related to the Stiltjes transformation associated to $X$, but I could not find the exact formula for this quantity.

Answer (score 1):

The Stieltjes transform is given by the normalized trace of the resolvent
$(X - I z)^{-1}$. With probability one, this is close, for every $z \in \mathbb{C}^+$, to the Stieltjes transform of the Marchenko-Pastur law associated with the spectral measure of $V$ when $n$ and $d$ are both large and comparable. A lot is known about the behavior of the Stieltjes transform as $z \rightarrow x \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $A$ is not a scalar multiple of the identity or constrained to have finite rank (rank is negligible with respect to d), I don't know any results for determining $\phi$. The only simplification that I can think of is that, if $V = I$, the distribution of $X$ is unitarily invariant, and so we can take $A$ to be diagonal without loss of generality. But, if $A$ isn't a multiple of the identity or has negligible rank w.r.t. d, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What do you mean by "normalized trace"

Comment: For a matrix $X$, normalized trace means $\dfrac{1}{d}Tr(X)$

Comment: Where can I find a proof of a result like "The Stieltjes transform is equal to the trace of the resolvent up to a factor $1/d$"?

Comment: I should clarify that I am referring to the Stieltjes transform of the empirical spectral distribution of $X$. This follows from the definition of the empirical spectral distribution and Stieltjes transform. For more on this, I recommend the book of Bai and Silverstein titled "Spectral Analysis of Large Dimensional Random Matrices"

Comment: I see, but even when $V = I_d$ and $A$ is diagonal, is it possible to compute the desired expectation in closed form?

Comment: In this case, $X$ has unitarily invariant distribution and the results from free probability might help you, but unless $A$ has some simple form (like a small number of distinct diagonal elements), then I doubt a closed form exists.

Comment: I am referring to results such as theorem 2.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0003043.pdf. Free probability tells us that the spectral measure of X + A converges almost surely  to the additive free convolution of the spectral measure of X and the spectral measure of A, which is linearized by the R-transform. But this is not straightforward to compute unless $A$ is something simple. This question might be better suited for mathoverflow.

Comment: Thank you, the reference is useful.